# Not sure what to do about error message "Conversion to double from cell is not possible."

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a program that finds the indices of a matrix G where there is only a single 1 for either a column index or a row index and removes any found index if it has a 1 for both the column and row index. Then I want to take these indices and use them as indices in an array U, which is where the trouble comes. The indices do not seem to be stored as integers and I'm not sure what they are being stored as or why. I'm quite new to Matlab (but thats probably obvious) and so I don't really understand how types work for Matlab or how they're assigned. So I'm not sure why I',m getting the error message mentioned in the title and I'm not sure what to do about it. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

I forgot to mention this before but G is a matrix that only contains 1s or 0s and U is an array of strings (i think what would be called a cell?)

```
function A = ISClinks(U, G)
B = [];
[rownum,colnum] = size(G);
j = 1;
for i=1:colnum
   s = sum(G(:,i));
   if s == 1
      B(j,:) = i;
      j = j + 1;
   end
end
for i=1:rownum
    s = sum(G(i,:));
    if s == 1
        if ismember(i, B)
            B(B == i) = [];
        else
            B(j,:) = i;
            j = j+1;
        end
    end
end
A = [];
for i=1:size(B,1)
    s = B(i,:);
    A(i,:) = U(s,:);
end
end
```

This is the problem code, but I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

```
A = [];
for i=1:size(B,1)
    s = B(i,:);
    A(i,:) = U(s,:);
end
```

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of typical input arguments (`U` and `G`) and the expected output?

Comment: Ye sorry, i just made an edit clarifying this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program seems to be structured as though it had been written in a language like C. In MATLAB, you can usually substitute specialized functions (e.g. `any()` ) for low-level loops in many cases. Your function could be written more efficiently as:

```
function A = ISClinks(U, G)
  % Find columns and rows that are set in the input
  active_columns=any(G,1);
  active_rows=any(G,2).';

  % (Optional) Prevent columns and rows with same index from being simultaneously set
  %exclusive_active_columns = active_columns & ~active_rows; %not needed; this line is only for illustrative purposes
  %exclusive_active_rows = active_rows & ~active_columns; %same as above

  % Merge column state vector and row state vector by XORing them
  active_indices=xor(active_columns,active_rows);

  % Select appropriate rows of matrix U
  A=U(active_indices,:);
end
```

This function does not cause errors with the example input matrices I tested. If `U` is a cell array (e.g. `U={'Lorem','ipsum'; 'dolor','sit'; 'amet','consectetur'}`), then return value `A` will also be a cell array.

Comment: I didn't know about these smaller functions, but thanks for the heads up. I've implemented this, but the problem is and i think i didn't explain this very well before, but it's supposed to get columns or rows that only a have a single 1 in them, which is why i was using the sum functions, but i think that i can figure that part out. Thanks